# Why does Collections.unmodifiableMap not check if the map passed is already an UnmodifiableMap?

Tags: java, performance

Looking at the `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap` implementation (OpenJDK 11):

```
    /**
     * Returns an <a href="Collection.html#unmodview">unmodifiable view</a> of the
     * specified map. Query operations on the returned map "read through"
     * to the specified map, and attempts to modify the returned
     * map, whether direct or via its collection views, result in an
     * {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.<p>
     *
     * The returned map will be serializable if the specified map
     * is serializable.
     *
     * @param <K> the class of the map keys
     * @param <V> the class of the map values
     * @param  m the map for which an unmodifiable view is to be returned.
     * @return an unmodifiable view of the specified map.
     */
    public static <K,V> Map<K,V> unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        return new UnmodifiableMap<>(m);
    }
```

My question is why does the implementation not do a check that the map passed might already be an 
`UnmodifiableMap`, something like this :

```
    public static <K,V> Map<K,V> unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        if(m instanceof UnmodifiableMap){
            return m;
        }
        return new UnmodifiableMap<>(m);
    }
```

Rather this question can be extended to all other un-modifiable collections, a simple check helps to avoid [unwanted stackoverflow errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384953/stackoverflowerror-from-collections-unmodifiablemap-get) as well as unnecessary wrapping.

I wanted to know if there was a reason why this is not being done?

Also it is sort of impossible (without using Reflection/Classloader magic) to do the check by the user as `UnmodifiableMap` is private.

Comment: `UnmodifiableMap` happens to be what **this** and **current** implementation of the method returns. Many other unmodifiable map types can exist. And, this `unmodifiableMap` method implementation can change in future to return a different class... I think doing `m instanceof UnmodifiableMap` would leave more questions than it would answer (yes, because there's no API/contrat for the 'unmodifiable' attribute).

Comment: In case they would want to **swap** the implementation with something else someday, they can go ahead and change the check to that implementation that day. Is there any issue with that?

Comment: Agreed. Except tests on maps serialized on the old version would lead to unpredictable results. This isn't a big deal, but I guess the performance gain wouldn't be much anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always saw that as somehow weird too, as a matter of fact when you do almost the same logical thing with Java 9 or newer, via:

```
    Map<String, Integer> left = Map.of("one", 1);
    Map<String, Integer> right = Map.copyOf(left);
    System.out.println(left == right); // true
```

you could see that the implementation *does* a check to see if this `Map` is known to be immutable already:

```
static <K, V> Map<K, V> copyOf(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
    if (map instanceof ImmutableCollections.AbstractImmutableMap) {
        return (Map<K,V>)map;
    } else {
        return (Map<K,V>)Map.ofEntries(map.entrySet().toArray(new Entry[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO there's no good reason for omitting the check. One comment says

> Many other unmodifiable map types can exist.

but this is no good reason either. With someone using a different implementation, the check would be ineffective, but still no problem.

The only reason for not doing the check can be performance. However, an `instanceof` (or class equality) check is pretty cheap and the eliminated indirection can easily offset

IMHO the current state is a bug; the check should be done, especially because of `UnmodifiableMap` being `private`, so that the test can't be done in user code.

OTOH the cases when this matters are rare and Java is very conservative, so I don't think it ever gets fixed. You may want to check the bug database to see whether this issue has been reported.

Comment: Oh, that is another thing I completely forgot about that it is sort of impossible for the user to do the check.

Comment: I agree with you, and [java-9 does the check internally, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855644/1059372)

Answer (score 2):

I would assume the reason your proposed check is not being done is that creating an instance of an `UnmodifiableMap` is really just creating a thin wrapper around the underlying map instance, rather than a deep copy.  To create a deep unmodifiable copy, you would have to do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> unmodMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(yourMap));
```

If this were the implementation, then checking if the map reference already points to an `UnmodifiableMap` could perhaps avoid the need to make a deep copy.

There may not be very much performance gain in avoiding wrapping an existing unmodifiable map a second (or third) time, so to keep the implementation simple, the creators just chose to not bother checking.

Comment: I understand that it does not create a deep copy, however I don't see why adding the check on what the passed map is over complicates stuff. People have been burned previously by running into a stack-overflow because of this.

Comment: @AdwaitKumar That stack overflow (the error, not the website) sounds like the result of bad recursive programming, where the authors were not paying attention to how many times they create an unmodified map instance.  It shouldn't be the job of this class to handle such cases.

Comment: Not just recursive programming, I have seen patterns (though might not be a good pattern) in codebases where functions which take in a `Map`, wrap it via `Collections#unmodifiableMap` to ensure that they mistakenly do not modify the map. This happens independently across multiple classes and sometimes lead to too much wrapping due to function call depth.